# Execute Http calls in async mode inside the blazor OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, blazor

I'm facing a weird issue with the OnAfterRenderAsync blazor lifecycle method. I'm making Http calls inside this method, some calls may take long time, but others fetchs data quickly. Following is a sample code:

```
   private List<MiniTrackedOrderDTO> orderStates;
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
       if (firstRender) { 
          orderStates =  await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<MiniTrackedOrderDTO>>("Salesman/GetOrderState");
       // second Http call
       // third Http call 
       this.StateHasChanged();
       }
    }
```

I know that the second call is the shorter one, so I want to update my view as soon as it finished, the current behaviour is that the view doesn't re-render until all the call gets finished. By putting a Console.WriteLine below each Http call, I noticed that the calls are executed sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay between calls, like:

```
   private List<MiniTrackedOrderDTO> orderStates;
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
       if (firstRender) { 
          orderStates =  await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<MiniTrackedOrderDTO>>("Salesman/GetOrderState");

       this.StateHasChanged();
       await Task.Delay(10);

       // second Http call
       this.StateHasChanged();
       await Task.Delay(10);

       // third Http call 
       this.StateHasChanged();
}
```